# Marionette. Add methods to view via behaviors

Tags: javascript, marionette

So I have:

1. Class `MySuperBehavior` extends `Marionette.Behavior`
2. Bunch of classes extends `Marionette.ItemView` and uses `MySuperBehavior`, like `tralalaView`, `trololoView` etc

I want to create method into MySuperBehavior which every instance of TralalaView and TrololoView can use. How can I do it correctly?

Sample code to illustrate:

```
 var mySuperBehavior =  Marionette.Behavior.extend({
        awesomeNonStaticMethod: function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
```

We suppose correct linking of classes

```
var tralalaView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    behaviors: {
      somebehavior: {
        behaviorClass: MySuperBehavior
      }
    }
  // some methods here
});

var instOfTralala = new tralalaView();
console.log(instOfTralala.awesomeNonStaticMethod()); // I want something like this
```

Comment: That should be right. If it's not working, are you sure `MySuperBehavior` refers to your `mySuperBehavior` variable?

Comment: @JasonTu, yes I'm sure in my case. This is just pseudocode to illustrate. Maybe i should create simple real snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like that:

```
 var mySuperBehavior =  Marionette.Behavior.extend({
        initialize: function(options, view){
            this.view.awesomeNonStaticMethod = this.awesomeNonStaticMethod
        }
        awesomeNonStaticMethod: function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
```